# TestCafe mock backend data being overridden

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a test that first logs in into a page, then selects a date range, on date picker, which queries an API to build a chart. I am trying to mock the data returned by the API with RequestMock
I announce the mock outside of the test

```
let conversionMock = RequestMock()
```

with .onRequestTo and .respond
then in my fixture I run

```
 fixture.requestHooks(conversionMock)
```

and finally when i select the datepicker time range in my test i run

```
await t.addRequestHooks(conversionMock)
```

When I run the test I see the data on the chart being populated for a split second, and then it's being overridden with the data the API actually returns. I suspect the reason for this is that the UI sends both OPTIONS and GET request to retrieve that data, and my mock only mocks the first request which is OPTIONS, and gets overridden by GET request.
How do I make sure my data is not overridden and stays with me?
I've tried calling multiple times in my test but that does not seem to help

```
await t.addRequestHooks(conversionMock)
```

Comment: If you use the `fixture.requestHooks` method, the attached hook will handle requests from all tests in the fixture. So, you can omit the use of the `t.addRequestHooks` method with the same hook in the test. Note that you can [pass a predicate function](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/requestmock/onrequestto.html#filter-with-a-predicate) to the `onRequestTo` method and filter requests by the method you used for the request. Ensure that both of the requests ("OPTIONS" and "GET") pass through the filter.

Comment: If this doesn't help, could you please share an example and a used RequestMock so I can reproduce your scenario?

Comment: @wentwrong adding a predicate function helped me, I've created separate hooks for "OPTIONS" and "GET" requests by targeting appropriate request.method; thank you!